# How can I compute simple addition on multiple .xyz files?

Tags: python, read-write

I am currently trying to write a Python program that will take 2 existing .xyz files (containing 3 columns of values separated by spaces), loop through them, add numbers from equivalent positions in each column of the list, then write those values to a separate .txt file in the same position.

For example, if I have the list:

```
(line denoting number of atoms)
(comment line)
(atom symbol) 1 1 1
(atom symbol) 2 2 2
(atom symbol) 3 3 3
```

and the list:

```
(line denoting number of atoms)
(comment line)
(atom symbol) 3 3 3
(atom symbol) 2 2 2
(atom symbol) 1 1 1
```

I want to make python create a new file in the form:

```
(line denoting number of atoms)
(comment line)
(atom symbol) 4 4 4
(atom symbol) 4 4 4
(atom symbol) 4 4 4
```

Currently my is giving me the error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

and my code is:

```
def sumen():
    infile_1 = input("Name of first file you wish to open as file using '.txt': ")
    infile_2 = input("Name of second file you wish to open as file using '.txt': ")
    outfile = input("Name the output file using '.txt': ")

    with open(infile_1, 'r') as myfile_1, open(infile_2, 'r') as myfile_2:
        for line1 in myfile_1.readlines():
            parts1 = line1.split('\n')
        for line2 in myfile_2.readlines():
            parts2 = line2.split('\n')

    with open(outfile, 'w') as outputfile:
        totalenergy = float(parts1) + float(parts2)

    print("The output was printed to:", outfile)

sumen()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
def sumen():
    infile_1 = input("Name of first file you wish to open as file using '.txt': ")
    infile_2 = input("Name of second file you wish to open as file using '.txt': ")
    outfile = input("Name the output file using '.txt': ")

    with open(infile_1, 'r') as myfile_1, \
         open(infile_2, 'r') as myfile_2, \
         open(outfile, 'w') as outputfile:

        for _ in range(2):  # copy first two lines of first file (and advance second)
            outputfile.write(next(myfile_1))
            next(myfile_2)

        for (line1, line2) in zip(myfile_1, myfile_2):
            parts1 = line1.split()
            parts2 = line2.split()
            totalenergy = [float(parts1[i]) + float(parts2[i]) for i in range(1, len(parts1))]
            outputfile.write('{} {}\n'.format(parts1[0], ' '.join(map(str, totalenergy))))

    print("The output was printed to:", outfile)

sumen()
```

For your sample input files, this will produce an output file that looks something like this:

```
(line denoting number of atoms)
(comment line)
(atom symbol) 4.0 4.0 4.0
(atom symbol) 4.0 4.0 4.0
(atom symbol) 4.0 4.0 4.0
```

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you!  The only minor problem is that  values in each row are printed with no spaces between them (e.g. 2 2 2 is being printed 222).

Comment: The `' '.join(map(str, totalenergy))` part should be putting `' '` characters between each of them.

Comment: Got it. That was my fault - I missed adding the space there. Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear. BTW, you might want to make this a little more robust as it makes a lot of assumptions about the two files—such as that they contain the same number of lines and the corresponding `atom symbol`s on the lines from each match.

Comment: Will this not work if the corresponding atom symbols are not the same? (because there will be variation in atom symbol -- C, N, O, & H). I am not sure if the files will contain the same number of lines, as this code is preliminary to any experimental data and I am an undergrad working on a new summer project I am still unfamiliar with.  However, if it is possible to make this code account for both of those things, that would be even better...   (Also, I apologize for my ignorance, I just recently started teaching myself python.)

Comment: Edit: when varying the atom symbol, the program still works, so I would only have to account for differences in list length.

Comment: That's because it doesn't verify that the atom symbol on the two lines are the same—which is what I was pointing out—instead it just copies the the symbol from the first file to the output file. You can check if they're different with: `if parts1[0] != parts2[0]:` or something similar. Of course you'll have to determine what you want to happen in those cases...

Comment: Ah, that is actually exactly what I would need. I believe the structures will be the same, thus copying from one file to another is ideal.  If the lists are not the same length, I'm sure I'll find myself confused again and on stackoverflow once again.

Comment: If they aren't the same length, the use of `zip()` will cause only the number of lines that the shortest one contains to be processed—just so you know. You could keep that from (silently) happening by comparing the numeric values on the first line of each file.

Comment: Oh, okay. I guess I'll cross that bridge within the next couple of days...

Answer (score 0):

In your function:

```
with open(infile_1, 'r') as myfile_1, open(infile_2, 'r') as myfile_2:
    for line1 in myfile_1.readlines():
        parts1 = line1.split('\n')
    for line2 in myfile_2.readlines():
        parts2 = line2.split('\n')
```

You need to split your lines by whitespace, as it's only split on new line characters (which *.readlines()* already does).

> What your code does: `parts1 = "1 1 1"`
>
> What you want it to do: `parts1 = ["1", "1", "1"]`

Split line1 and line2 with `.split()` to split on all whitespace instead.

Edit: You'll also need to indent the portion of writing to the output file to be inside the loop, since parts1 and parts2 are overwritten each time. Try unifying all your code in a manner similar to this:

```
with open(infile_1, 'r') as myfile_1, open(infile_2, 'r') as myfile_2, open(outfile, 'w') as outputfile:
    for line1, line2 in zip(myfile_1.readlines(), myfile_2.readlines()):
        parts1 = line1.split()
        parts2 = line2.split()
        totalenergy = []
        for part1, part2 in zip(parts1, parts2):
            totalenergy.append(float(part1) + float(part2))
        outputfile.write(str(totalenergy) + '\n')
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your example with parts1 (sorry, I'm just starting to learn python)

Comment: When _for line1 in myfile_1.readlines()_ is called,  line1 is a single line from the input file.
    e.g. line1 = "(atom symbol) 1 1 1" // Or without the (atom symbol) portion
You need to continue splitting line1 to be a list of ["1", "1", "1"] by calling _line1.split()_. This way, float() can be called on each of the elements in line1.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: This works **almost**. All the right values are being summed, however, when writing to the new file it is writing them as 1 vertical list instead of maintaining their position in 3 separate columns.

Comment: You'll need to make total energy a list, then append that list instead and do the write outside of the loop. I've updated the above example.

Comment: That is now printing 3 lists per line (e.g. for lists 1 2 3 and 4 5 6, the result is:  [5] [5, 7] [5, 7, 9] etc. for the whole list) where each of the aforementioned is a new list.

Comment: No problem, you can accept this answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your looping algorithm is wrong. What you want is to parse file1 and file2 line by line, and work on one line of each file at a time before moving to the next line.

I suggest you rewrite it like this:

```
with open(infile_1, 'r') as myfile_1, open(infile_2, 'r') as myfile_2, open(outfile, 'w') as myfile_3:
    f3 = []
    for (line1, line2) in zip(myfile_1.readlines(), myfile_2.readlines()):
        values1 = line1.split()[1:]
        values2 = line2.split()[1:]
        f3.append(' '.join([str(float(x) + float(y)) for x, y in zip(values1, values2)])+'\n')
        pass
    myfile_3.writelines(f3)
```

Comment: Trying it this way is taking the lines of interest from each file (e.g. 1 1 1 and 3 3 3) and printing them together. I am looking to take each value, add it to the other and print the sum to a new file (e.g. 4 4 4).

Comment: I've got it. My suggestion is about how you loop through the files, not how you get values from lines. For example, in your algorithm, the value of parts1 is the value of the last line of your file only...

Comment: Got it. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: I wrote it a bit further for you to see how you can make it. I think this is pretty much what you want

Comment: When I do that, I get the error: IndexError: list index out of range. My list only has 3 columns, though, so I'm not quite sure why this is occurring.

Comment: OK, I was unsure about how many values you have per line. I rewrote it to just ignore the 1st value, which seems to be an atom symbol. You may paste an extract of your files to help us help you :)

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: Now with my code you print exactly like you want. Just need to push it into the new file and job's done :-)

Comment: That worked, but it is printing in python - not to a new file.

Comment: Added the part to write into file

Comment: Made the code shorter, thanks to suggestions in other answers

Comment: That time I was given the error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.  However, martineau has already adequately solved the problem, so don't feel obligated to make more edits. Thank you much, though!